# What's the best and fastest way to save Map in Android?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, memory

I need to save Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String[], Integer>>. I try to convert string to map and back using  JSON and then I add map to SharedPreferences. The second way is Java serialization. And the another one which I heard but have not use yet is a PaperDB (Github Link Of PaperDB : https://github.com/pilgr/Paper). So, tell me what's the best way to save Map. And if you have other suggestions how to do that which I do not said about share with me(if that is better way).

Comment: `Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String[], Integer>>` is a very strange tipe of object to manipulate, are you sure about what you are doing? I mean, are you sure there is no better way to do it?

Comment: I guess, yes. Don't you want to say that it's impossible to save that?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that in OOP it's a bit strange to find this kind of structure without some kind of encapsulation ... but this does not mean that it's not possible to do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and fastest way is by using Serializable interface:

```
final Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String[], Integer>> mapObject = new HashMap<>();
...
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = context.openFileOutput("/...path...", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    os.writeObject(mapObject);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(....);
} finally {
    if (fos != null) {
        try { fos.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) { /*nothing*/ }
    }
}
```

Comment: tell me please what "/.....path....." must be(absolute path or name of file) and which file extension should I use. I'm asking because I have this exception"read only file system" and I can't solve it for almost 2 days.

Comment: So you're writing in a place where you cannot write a file. You need some knowledge about Android Storage and choose/create appropriate Path according to your needs. There are plenty of Answers about Storage Paths here in Stackoverflow....